# Statistics Parameters in python?

Tags: python, statistics

Can anyone tell me how get model summary in pyhton.
As in R we can get simply by summary(model.fit).
I want to find the F statistics , p value ,Standard error in python for my given regression model fitted on dataset.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(x,y)
```

I want summary for this model.

Comment: The package you choose to train your model should have those capabilities.  Since you haven't shown your modeling code,  we can't give you specific help in finding the summary statistics.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not make much sense because you do not state what you want to use to fit your model. But if you use, e.g., `scipy` and linear regression is fine for you, you can proceed is described here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

Comment: thanks , I used this package and got desired results.